# Override maven release repository durning deploy

Tags: maven, plugins, release

I am working on an open source library and want to have releases sent to an internal artifactory server.  I have been using maven's `distributionManagement` and overriding `altDeploymentRepository` to point to the internal server (so its never in the pom).  This works fine when I do `deploy:deploy` but when I use the maven release plugin this seems to get ignored.

```
mvn clean -DaltDeploymentRepository=central::default::internalhost deploy ## works
mvn clean -DaltDeploymentRepository=central::default::internalhost release:perform ## fails, doesn't pick up this setting
```

How can I override the repository via command line when the release plugin runs deploy?

Comment: Can't you edit the POM to redefine the distribution management information?

Comment: Try this  `mvn release:perform -Darguments=-DaltDeploymentRepository=myvalue`.

Comment: @yorkw You should post this as a full answer as it's the correct one.

Comment: what does `central::default::internalhost` mean? shouldn't it be like some urls?

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
altReleaseDeploymentRepository
```

It has the same syntaxes than altDeploymentRepository

More in: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html

Comment: Although how you would pass username/password in it?

Comment: @old-monk the format is "some-id:url", the credentials for the server "some-id" are on your `~/.m2/settings.xml` file.

Answer (score 6):

> mvn release:perform -Darguments=-DaltDeploymentRepository=myvalue

the trick is: '-Dargument'

Valid resolution is in **yorkw** comment (for maven-deploy-plugin in version 2.7)
When you use higher version of maven-deploy-plugin (e.g. 2.8) then use parameter 
altReleaseDeploymentRepository.

[maven-deploy-plugin doc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html)

Answer (score -1):

On the version you're working on, you should edit the pom to change the distribution management section to use your internal repository.